# PHP Soap Client

Tags: php, xml, soap

HI,

I have this xml I'm trying to make parameter for SOAP Client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<RequestGenerateInvoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="XML">
  <Type>enAdd</Type> 
  <Invoice>
      <InvoiceNumber>5</InvoiceNumber> 
      <InvoiceIDTxt>101</InvoiceIDTxt> 
      <AccountIDTxt>1001</AccountIDTxt> 
      <InvoiceDate>2011-02-21T15:04:42.8500736+02:00</InvoiceDate> 
      <Code>1</Code> 
      <Details>Some Details</Details> 
      <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
      <Amount>10</Amount> 
      <AmountDue>20</AmountDue> 
      <FromDate>2011-02-21T15:04:42.8490735+02:00</FromDate> 
      <ToDate>2011-02-21T15:04:42.8530738+02:00</ToDate> 
      <Months>7</Months> 
      <IsPrinted>false</IsPrinted> 
      <Paid>0</Paid> 
      <CardNumber>101</CardNumber> 
      <PrevAccBalance>100</PrevAccBalance> 
      <RealUsageAmount>80</RealUsageAmount> 
      <LocationID>0</LocationID> 
      <BatchNumber>1</BatchNumber> 
      <BatchText>Some Text</BatchText> 
  </Invoice>
  <RequestLocationID>0</RequestLocationID> 
  <RequestDateTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</RequestDateTime> 
</RequestGenerateInvoice>
```

So far my script is:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://Some.?wsdl");
$client->MakeInvoice(array('Type'=>'enAdd', 
                           'Invoice'=> array('InvoiceNumber' => '101', 
                                             'InvoiceIDTxt' => '101', 
                                             'AccountIDTxt' => '2',......), 
                           'RequestLocationID'=>'2', 
                           'RequestDateTime'=>'0001-01-01T00:00:00'));
```

But I'm keep getting no response from the server

Comment: Hi. Wecome to SO. We can't read your XML code as things stand. To get your code formatted nicely, please indent it by 4 characters. Please edit the question to make it more readable. Thanks. (see the "How to Ask" info box on the page when you're writing the question for more info on how to format your question)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SoapClient->_*getLastRequest()*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) and [SoapClient->_getLastResponse()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php) to see what's going on under the hood.  Note that you need to switch this feature on in the `SoapClient` constructor:

```
$client = SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error message Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.DPTrEncDec, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. in C:\localhost\www\test\INDEX.PHP:330 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('UpdateAccountBa...', Array) #1 C:\localhost\www\test\INDEX.PHP(330): SoapClient->UpdateAccountBalance(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\localhost\www\test\INDEX.PHP on line 330

Comment: That means your Soap call is generating an exception on the remote server - you should talk to the owner of that server and give them the XML from __getLastResponse().  Use a try/catch to catch the error and print out the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need Content-Type: text/xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this XML is part of a SOAP communication. There is no SOAP envelope and body?! This seems to be a ReST API. Anyway you should read the documentation of the API.

If you are only interested in generating the printed XML via PHP you can use either [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).